# Need to filter mousemove event only when low speed of mouse moving

Tags: rxjs

in case when user very fast dragging via observable mousemove event, we don't need to emit each px this events, only when he trying to aim before drop element (we can catch this moment bcs speed of mouse will be low), is there any trick for this?

mb some case to get speed via px/per seconds then filter or etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a `pairwise` comparison of the mouse position, measuring the distance between events and filtering out high velocity moves:

```js
const { fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { pairwise, map, filter } = rxjs.operators;

const block = document.getElementById('block');
const mousemove$ = fromEvent(block, 'mousemove');

mousemove$.pipe(
  // filter out high velocity movements
  pairwise(),
  map(([a, b]) => ({
    d: getDistance(a,b),
    x: b.x,
    y: b.y
  })),
  filter(e => e.d < 10)
).subscribe(e => {
  console.log(e.x, e.y);
});

function getDistance(a, b){
  return Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2)
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #block {
    margin: 3rem;
    padding: 6rem;
    background: rebeccapurple;
  }
</style>

<div id="block"></div>
```

This depends on the rate of browser emitting and handling those events.

**So you'll probably will need to add [`timeInterval`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/timeInterval/) to calculate the speed, not just the delta**.

--

**OR** you could achieve this by using [debounceTime, throttleTime, auditTime or sampleTime](https://thinkrx.io/gist/304b955e27ea88f622094b671cdfbb7b).

[image: debounceTime vs throttleTime vs auditTime vs sampleTime]

Heres an example using `sampleTime` 300ms, that I would recommend:

```js
const { fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { sampleTime } = rxjs.operators;

const block = document.getElementById('block');
const mousemove$ = fromEvent(block, 'mousemove');

mousemove$.pipe(
  // sample only once per 300ms
  sampleTime(300)
).subscribe(e => {
  console.log(e.x, e.y);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #block {
    margin: 3rem;
    padding: 6rem;
    background: rebeccapurple;
  }
</style>

<div id="block"></div>
```

**Surely**, you could also combine "delta move" measuring with "sampling"

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks that why I want to track low speed, but mb u know how we can use sampleTime if `filter(e => e.d < 10)` only in case when this filter is false? so I mean when we slow dragging then don't use sampleTime for this pipe selector

Comment: @VyacheslavZhabitsky, please note that I've updated my answer to mention `timeInterval` that will let you calculate speed instead of just a delta.

Comment: @VyacheslavZhabitsky To have `sampleTime` based on filter, I think you'll have to merge two streams: `merge(low_speed_movements$, high_speed_movements_with_throttle$)` or somehow make a smarter use of that `timeInterval`. **Yet, I have a strong feeling that you're overengineering this.** Instead of smart throttling, you could, for example, just measure distance to the drop target and filter out events that happen too far. Or have a wrapping div around drop targets to bind `mousemove` to. If you could share your real usecase we could be of a better help.

Comment: I just have stupid feature for magnetize and show gridline measures like in photosop of dragged element))) so no overengineering

many thanks !!!

Comment: @VyacheslavZhabitsky, np. If this answer will help you — please, consider accepting it and definitely share the final combo you'll use!